# Return DaysHoursMins with individual returns

Tags: javascript

Current code that I have is this, but it is not returning individual values:
I want to make days, hours and minutes individual values to use with another javascript codes..

```
function convertToDaysHoursMins(time, allowzero = false)
{
    if (!allowzero && (time === 0 || time < 1))
        return 'unlimited';
    else if(allowzero && (time === 0 || time < 1))
        return '0m';

    let format = '';

    days       = Math.floor(time / 1440);
    if(days > 0) format = format + days + 'd ';

    hours      = Math.floor(time / 60);
    if(hours > 0 && (hours % 24) != 0) format = format + (hours - (days * 24)) + 'h '

    format 
    minutes    = (time % 60);
    if(minutes > 0) format = format + minutes + 'm';

    return [days, hours, minutes];
}
```

Comment: First try to transform your code in javascript and then if you have stuck, come back and ask how to solve the problem

Comment: There might be a little confusion here. Unix time is a value in seconds (or milliseconds, microseconds, etc depending of the precision) whereas your code is using a value in minutes (unless your not looking for the real number of day ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  function convertToDaysHoursMins(time, allowzero = false)
  {
      if (!allowzero && (time === 0 || time < 1))
          return 'unlimited';
      else if(allowzero && (time === 0 || time < 1))
          return [0,0,0];
  
  
      days       = Math.floor(time / 1440);
  
      hours      = Math.floor(time / 60);
      if(hours > 0 && (hours % 24) != 0) hours = hours - (days * 24)
  
      minutes    = (time % 60);
  
      return [days, hours, minutes]; 
  }
  
  const result = convertToDaysHoursMins(4556);
  console.log(result[0]);
  console.log(result[1]);
  console.log(result[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function convertToDaysHoursMins(time, allowzero = false)
{
    if (!allowzero && (time === 0 || time < 1))
        return 'unlimited';
    else if(allowzero && (time === 0 || time < 1))
        return '0m';

    let format = '';

    days       = Math.floor(time / 1440);
    if(days > 0) format = format + days + 'd ';

    hours      = Math.floor(time / 60);
    if(hours > 0 && (hours % 24) != 0) format = format + (hours - (days * 24)) + 'h '

    format 
    minutes    = (time % 60);
    if(minutes > 0) format = format + minutes + 'm';

    if(format !== '')
        return format
    else
        return '-';
}

console.log(convertToDaysHoursMins(4556))
```

Comment: At the end `format` could never be null since it's initial value is an empty string. You should use `if(format != "")` or just `if(format)`

Comment: Works like a charm, I already made my own work, but this looks clear!

Comment: Is it possible tho to instead of return format, I can return them individually? for example, return days + hours + minutes so that if I want to use those variables I can?? @Jose Marin

Comment: remove:     if(format !== '')
        return format
    else
        return '-';
and substitute for======>
return [days, hours, minutes]

Comment: This you can use: const result = convertToDaysHoursMins(4556)
console.log(result[0])
console.log(result[1])
console.log(result[2])

Comment: Can you create a new question so I can paste the new answer that matches the question?

Comment: Can you change this question specifying exactly with the new requirements?

Comment: @JoseMarin dont forget ;)